# Question about fitting non-attacking rooks on a board

Tags: combinatorics

Hope that someones can give me hints to solve the following problem:
How many ways can $N$ non-attacking rooks fit on a $N$ by $N$ board if:

(a) none can be on the main length N diagonal?

(b) none can be on either length N diagonal?

Comment: So for $N=3$ you get $5.5$? Are you sure you typed that formula right?

Comment: I think I get wrong answear.

Comment: The **first** step in attacking a counting problem is to collect some data by counting the things by hand for some small values of $N$, right? **Right?** [You do that because (a) counting by hand might help you to understand the problem, to See What's Going On, (b) anywau, when you do come up with a formula, you'll have some numbers to test it on; (c) showing us the numbers satisfies the show-your-work requirement for this site; (d) in the worst case, the numbers will help you cheat by looking up the solution on the web.] So, how far did you get, and what numbers did you come up with?

Answer (score 2):

For (a) the answer is equal to the number of permutations of a set of size $N$ which don't fix a point [sometimes called the umbrella problem because of the $N$ absent-minded professors who all take the wrong umbrella home]. The rook on each row has a column number different from the row number. This is a classical example of the use of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to count [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

I should understand that thoroughly before moving on to part $(b)$.

Comment: The story I heard with that problem is $N$ guys at a party toss their keys in a hat and each takes someone else's key.

Comment: @widapol, even before you do part (a), you could try to answer part (b) **in terms of** the answer to part (a). Namely, if you call the answer to part (a) $D_N$, you can use the in-and-out (aka inclusion-exclusion) principle to write the answer to (b) in terms of $D_N$.